# how to center the elements that are inside a box

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I need to center the elements that are inside a box. I tried to achieve it by using `justify-content: center;` but it is not working. What else can I do?

Notice that I have already used the `justify-content: center;` to bring the boxes to the center of the page.

```css
.pricing-container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 90vh;
}

.pricing-plan {
  border: 5px solid ghostwhite;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: gainsboro;
  border-radius: 10%;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="pricing-container">
    <div class="pricing-plan">
      <div class="plan-title">Basic</div>
      <div class="plan-price">$9.99/month</div>
      <ul class="plan-features">
        <li>✅ 10GB Storage</li>
        <li>✅ 1 User</li>
        <li> Support</li>
      </ul>
      <button class="plan-button">Sign Up</a>
   </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: put the code. Its difficult to pull the code from the snippet

Comment: Please post the code as text and not as an image, and create a [mcve] including the HTML you want to style and your current CSS.

Comment: @Guilherme Welcome to Stack Overflow, that's what hundreds of people do every single day. Not sure if Stack Overflow did mention somewhere that we're robots who can read/write/debug code from images, hmm....

Comment: @KevinM.Mansour that you ever hear about help me to help you? He is not helping with that img, simple that.

Comment: @Guilherme Instead of writing `that is a joke` when it was already said that it should be posted as text you could point to  [How to ask: DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or directly to [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551),

Comment: @KevinM.Mansour because this seems more like someone joking than actually asking.

Comment: What do you mean by  `I need to center the elements that are inside a box`? It is not really clear what it then should look like. (E.g. is it about entering vertically or horizontally)

Answer (score 0):

Put this code into the class of `(.pricing-plan)` instead of `(.pricing-container)`

```css
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
flex-direction: column;
```